# I have an R package hosted in a private bitbucket repo. Can I share the package with users who don't have access to the repo?

Tags: r, git, bitbucket, devtools

In other words, is there a way that a user can employ `devtools::install_bitbucket()` or `devtools::install_git()` to install the package on their local machine without me having to give them access to the repo?

Comment: AFAIK access to a private Bitbucket repo is limited to people who have been added to that repo.

Comment: something/somebody will certainly have to have read access to the repo

Comment: If you build the package, you can send the tar.gz file. The users can install locally. In Rstudio, just change the location in the `install.from` box.